# Sql to excel comparison

Tags: sql, excel

I exported the SQL query into excel and trying to compare with another spreadsheet. one of the comparison coloumn is date. SQL query output returns: 03-JAN-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM. The other excel has the same value for date 03-Jan-18. I truncate the date value from the timestamp using left(cell reference,9), but when comparing this with the excel it returns no match. how do I format the value from SQL to match excel date format.

Comment: are you looking for the SQL function `date_trunc()`? (not sure which version of SQL this is from, if this doesn't work, I'd google "date_trunc() [sqlversion]")

Comment: dates are tricky.  `Left()` returns a string.  so try turning it into a number : `=--LEFT(...)`

Comment: Select both columns in excel and format to date only (don't use left() in excel for date formatting)...excel should be able to figure it out from there.   You're doing this a little backwards though, far easier to import excel into SQL and compare with SQL.

Comment: Thanks Scott. appending -- in front of date works.

Comment: @Twelfth As far as I know  `03-JAN-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM` Excel will see it as text and not a date, at least with my version.  and the dates, if they are true dates and not text that looks like dates, do not need to be formatted similarly in excel for it to find a duplicate as the underlying value is a number.